# How can I efficiently transfer data from a NumPy array to a QPolygonF when using PySide?

Tags: python, numpy, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I want do draw polylines with many control points in a PyQt4 / PySide application. The point coordinates come from a NumPy array and must be put into a `QPolygonF` in order to be drawn with `QPainter.drawPolyline(...)`.

With PyQt4, this can be done efficiently e.g. with something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

n = 3
qpoints = QPolygonF(n)
vptr = qpoints.data()
vptr.setsize(8*2*n)
aa = np.ndarray( shape=(n,2), dtype=np.float64, buffer=buffer(vptr))
aa.setflags(write=True)
aa[:,0] = np.arange(n)
aa[:,1] = np.arange(n)
for i in range(n):
    print qpoints.at(i)
```

This works, because, when using PyQt4, `QPolygonF.data()` returns something (a `sip.voidptr` object) which speaks the Python buffer protocol.

The problem now is that if I try to run the above code using PySide instead of PyQt4, `QPolygonF.data()` just returns a `QPointF` object (with the coordinates of the first point in the `QPolygonF`) and is thus useless.

So my question is: is there any known workaround to this? How can I, with PySide, put data into a `QPolygonF` without inserting `QPointF` objects, element-wise?

Comment: Have you tried asking about this on the PySide mailing list? It looks to me like a deficiency with PySide that should be fixed so I'd post on the mailing list of bug tracker and see if anyone there can help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an efficient way of writing a Numpy array into the memory block pointed by a QPolygonF object using PySide2:
https://github.com/PierreRaybaut/PythonQwt/blob/master/qwt/plot_curve.py#L63
(See function "array2d_to_qpolygonf")

This is as efficient as with PyQt4 or PyQt5.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
from pylab import *
from PySide.QtGui import QPolygonF
from PySide.QtCore import QPointF

xy = resize(arange(10),(2,10)).T

qPlg = QPolygonF()
for p in xy:
    qPlg.append(QPointF(*p))
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However this inserts QPointF objects element-wise into the QPolygonF which is exactly what I want to circumvent. It is too slow for my application.

Comment: Got you, that makes things a bit more interesting!

Answer (score 0):

In PyQt6, you can accelerate the code given by Pierre Raybaut (up to a factor three on my computer) by replacing

```py
polyline = QPolygonF([QPointF(0, 0)] * size)
```

by

```py
polyline = QPolygonF([QPointF(0, 0)])
polyline.fill(QPointF(0, 0),size)
```

This indeed removes the need of creating a long Python list.

However, if you want to add this polygon to a series with QChart.addSeries, the time of this operation is  pretty long, but it still allows working fluently up to 1 million points with my Core i7 10th gen, on Ubuntu 22.04.